# get the object property in another class

Tags: java

i have a Emp class which have one property empName.i am setting this property in empCreate class.i want to get this property in Main class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         // here i want to get empName which i set it in empCreate.java
    }
}
```

how i can do this. please suggest.

---

i have Emp.java:

```
public class Emp { 
private String empName; 

    public String getEmpName() { 
        return empName; 
    } 

    public void setEmpName(String empName) { 
        this.empName = empName; 
    } 
}
```

and empCreate.java:

```
public class empCreate { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Emp emp= new Emp(); 
        emp.setEmpName("abc"); 
    } 
}
```

i want to get this property in Main.java which i set it in empCreate.java

Comment: I would really suggest reading some tutorials before asking here.  Accessing the members of a class is one of the simplest things you can do in Java.

Comment: i have Emp.java: public class Emp {
 private String empName;
 public String getEmpName() {
  return empName;
 }
 public void setEmpName(String empName) {
  this.empName = empName;
 }
}  and empCreate.java: public class empCreate {
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Emp emp= new Emp();
 emp.setEmpName("abc");
 }
 }  i want to get this property in Main.java which i set it in empCreate.java

Comment: The code snippets you've provided show a clear lack of understanding of Java/OOP. Start with an introductory book.

Comment: Why don't you just create Emp emp inside Main?!? :) Maybe it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve but could a Factory Pattern help somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't have two main methods**. Anyway, I strongly suggest you read the [Declaring Member Variables](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) tutorial. This is *very* basic stuff.

I recommend you refactor your `empCreate` class to include a constructor and a getter for your `Emp` instance. For instance,

```
public class empCreate { 
    private Emp emp;

    public empCreate() { 
        emp = new Emp(); 
        emp.setEmpName("abc"); 
    } 

    public Emp getEmp(){
        return emp;
    }
}
```

And then, in your `Main` class, you can simply do the following -

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        empCreate ec = new empCreate();
        String empName = ec.getEmp().getEmpName(); // obtain the emp name
    }
}
```

Comment: @user783160 - Perhaps it's better to recommend reading the [Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) tutorial..

Answer (score 1):

Add a method to `Emp` called `getName()` that returns the name.  Then invoke that method when you want the name.

```
class Emp
{
    String name;
    ....
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it by creating a new instance of empCreate or directly calling that property after giving an static reference to empCreate.